# System.setProperty not working for file.encoding in Java

Tags: java, file, utf-8, system

I have this simple program where Im trying to create a txt file with UTF-8 format. However, I see that the file is not encoded with UTF-8 but shows the encoding is set to ANSI. Below is the output. Can you please help.

```
public class fileCreate {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
             System.out.println("Before encoding: "+System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
             System.setProperty("file.encoding","UTF-8");
             System.out.println("After encoding: "+System.getProperty("file.encoding")); 

             File file = new File("C:/tmp/myfile_UTF-8.txt");

             if(file.createNewFile())System.out.println("Success!");
               else System.out.println ("Error, file already exists.");
          }
          catch(IOException ioe) {
          ioe.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
   }
```

Output:

Before encoding: Cp1252

After encoding: UTF-8

Success!

Comment: Text files don't store encoding unless you plan to write UTF-8 BOM. Please read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: I am getting different o/p: `Before encoding: UTF-8
After encoding: UTF-8
Success!`

Comment: ...maybe you should try not an empty file...since this is empty in any encoding...what you see & what it shows...is up to the one who shows/sees

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new file, it is initially empty. "Encoding" is not a property of the file, it is how you interpret its content bytes. That is also why you have to specify the encoding before reading and writing, because it is not stored anywhere.

Without content, the encoding is kind of undefined. Your editor probably picks its first guess, which might be ASCII. But empty content can probably be decoded with any encoding.

If you write some text to the file in your code, it will be encoded in UTF-8. Your editor will then show its encoding as such too (provided it is a good one and can detect it correctly).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below code to create UTF-8 file

```
PrintWriter out1 = new PrintWriter(new File("C:/tmp/myfile_UTF-8.txt"), "UTF-8");
```